# Python Parallel Matrix Vector Multiplication

Tags: python, matrix, multiprocessing, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply each column of a matrix by a vector element-wise.

I have a serial solution that works correctly.

```
    for i in range(0,temp.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0,temp.shape[1]):
             temp[i,j] = temp[i,j] * h[i,0]
```

Below is the parallel solution that works for what i am trying to do, but does not return the same matrix as the above code.

```
def mv_mult(start_col,end_col,M,V):
for i in range(0,M.shape[0]):
    for j in range(start_col,end_col):
        M[i,j] = M[i,j] * V[i,0]

num_threads = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
threads = []
extra = temp.shape[1] % num_threads
start_col = 0
jump = temp.shape[1] / num_threads
for i in range(0,num_threads):
    print 'starting thread ', i
    if (i <  extra)
        args = start_col, start_col+jump+1,temp,h
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=mv_mult,args=args)
        p.start()
        threads.append(p)
        start_col += jump+1
    else:
        args = start_col, start_col+jump,temp,h
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=mv_mult,args=args)
        p.start()
        threads.append(p)
        start_col += jump

for i in threads:
    i.join()
```

I am relatively new to Python, but as far as I know everything is pass by reference, so the temp matrix passed to each new process is the same object, so it should work the same as the serial solution, minus the fact that it is split up by column.

Any ideas as to why it is not working?

Comment: Best by far to do this with numpy, and make sure your numpy is linked against a threaded BLAS (Atlas, OpenBLAS).  You don't want to be writing your own linear algebra routines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just the numpy `multiply` operation:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.matrix(numpy.ones((5,5)))
b = numpy.arange(5).reshape(5,1)
print a
print b    
#[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
# [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
# [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
# [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
# [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
#[[0]
# [1]
# [2]
# [3]
# [4]]

c = numpy.multiply(a,b)
print c
#[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
# [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
# [ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]
# [ 3.  3.  3.  3.  3.]
# [ 4.  4.  4.  4.  4.]]
```

(Note that in your serial version you're multiplying rows, not columns).

Comparing the time of this to your serial version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy
import numpy.random
import numpy.linalg
import sys
import time

def init(n):
    a = numpy.matrix(numpy.random.rand(n,n))
    b = numpy.random.rand(n,1)
    b = b.reshape((n,1))
    return a,b

def np_mult(a, b):
    c = numpy.multiply(a,b)
    return c

def manual_mult(a,b):
    c = numpy.matrix(numpy.zeros_like(a))
    for i in range(0,a.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0,a.shape[1]):
             c[i,j] = a[i,j] * b[i]
    return c

def main(argv=None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv

    n = int(argv[1])
    niters = int(argv[2])
    a,b = init(n)

    start = time.time()
    for i in xrange(niters):
        cnp = np_mult(a,b)
    end = time.time()

    nptime = (end-start)/niters
    print 'Numpy: ', nptime

    start = time.time()
    for i in xrange(niters):
        cm = manual_mult(a,b)
    end = time.time()

    manualtime = (end-start)/niters
    print 'Manual: ', manualtime
    print 'Speed difference = ', manualtime/nptime
    print 'Diff = ', numpy.linalg.norm(cm - cnp)/numpy.linalg.norm(cnp)

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Running with a few small sizes gives:

```
$ ./mult.py 50 5
Numpy:  3.48091125488e-05
mManual:  0.021101808548
Speed difference =  606.215068493
Diff =  0.0

$ ./mult.py 100 5
Numpy:  6.59942626953e-05
Manual:  0.0830503940582
Speed difference =  1258.44869942
Diff =  0.0

$ ./mult.py 500 5
Numpy:  0.000931406021118
Manual:  2.08903641701
Speed difference =  2242.88481032
Diff =  0.0
```

with speed differences completely dwarfing anything you could make up for with parallelism.

Comment: Thank you very much. This does look like what I'm trying to do. I'm translating Matlab into Python. Thanks for the timings too.

Comment: I ended up using this as my solution. My matrices were about 13000x13000. It is part of a function that is called multiple times within a loop. My loop is now down to 3:30 per iteration, from 12min.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have an array, first try using numpy's vectorized calculations:

```
M[:,startcol:endcol] *= V[:,0]
```

you may well find this is faster than any parallelization tricks you can do, and if not, you'd still be better off using a similar line and sending chunks of the matrix to each process, not individual elements.

Comment: I had tried using this at first, but they are matrices rather than arrays and I get an error when indexing by slices. It looks like python is pass by assignment rather than reference. Just got back from lunch, so I'm starting to look into that.

Comment: You could also look at [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/wiki) which may speed up very large calculations that are elementwise?

Comment: Good idea, Mark M, numexpr is very good for accelerating array expressions for large calculations, but it shines when the expressions contain many terms that would otherwise create temporary arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Other people have addressed the correct way to solve your problem, I just wanted to respond to:

> so the temp matrix passed to each new process is the same object, so
>   it should work the same as the serial solution,

This breaks down when you're trying to do multiprocessing -- parallel processes can't have any shared memory, so they can't all access the same array at the same time. I believe that you're getting N_WORKERS copies of your array passed out to the workers. Each worker works on his own copy and then throws away the result when he stops. I would expect that you get back the same matrices at the end that you started with.

If you want to take this approach, you need to have them return their own copy at the end and then merge them back together (which kills any efficiency gains you might have gotten).